# Strange Issue With Http Call

Tags: c#, wcf, httpwebrequest, http-post

I am calling a wcf method by using http web request. works great with GET methods, but when i try to call a POST method it does not work properly. below is the code from where i cam calling. 
error is "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request"

**Code Snippter**

```
       string postData = string.Format("Id={0}", "1");
        HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:4567/ClientService.svc/UpdateNotificationStatus");
        webRequest.Method = "POST";
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-urlencoded";
        webRequest.ContentLength = postData.Length;

        using (StreamWriter requestWriter2 = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            requestWriter2.Write(postData);
        }

        using (StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()))
        {
            // dumps the HTML from the response into a string variable
            postData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Below is my Operation Contract in WCF service. Strange thing is that when i remove the parameters from the OperationContract e.g. "ID", this method works.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "updateNotificationStatus")]
    void UpdateNotificationStatus(string Id);

    public void UpdateNotificationStatus(string Id)
    {
        try
        {                                

            wmas_subsDataContext dc = new wmas_subsDataContext();

            var ObjNotification = dc.tbPushNotifications.Where(p => p.ID == Convert.ToInt32(Id));

            if (ObjNotification.ToList().Count > 0)
            {
                ObjNotification.First().Status = "Completed";
            }

            dc.SubmitChanges();                
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogFile.WriteException(ex);
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What actually happens is far more useful that vaguely telling us that it "does not work properly".

Comment: i get this error on client however i have declared it in wcf service. The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: `ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";` != `RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`

Comment: what that means @CodeCaster

Comment: It means you're getting a "bad request" because you're sending a bad request. Your service expects JSON, so the request content type should be "application/json".

Comment: @codeCaster .. problem is still there. i changed the content type to the one you mentioned but i get 404 error.

Comment: That's a different error.

Comment: Now getting The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. Please see my original post, i have changed the code.

Comment: interesting thing : i am able to call this wcf api using fiddler. POST /ClientService.svc/UpdateNotificationStatus HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.15.52:4567
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Type: text/json
Content-Length: 1

{"Id":"1" }